# Sqlite: Insert if not exist, Update if exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with 2 tables like this:

```
cg_resp
id  | name   | email
1   | George | george@yahoo.com
```

`id` column is `primary_key`,`autoincremented` and `name` is `unique`

and

```
equip_info
id  | description  | cg_resp_id 
1   | Caliper      | 1
```

In the application form I have 2 edit boxes named `edit_resp_name` and `edit_resp_email`

If user insert a new responsible name like `John` with the email `john@yahoo.com`  then during the save of form I would like to `insert` a new responsible into `cg_resp` table, get the last inserted `id` and update it to `equip_info.cg_resp_id`.

If the user maintain the name `George` but it's updating the email like `george01@gmail.com` then I would like to `update` the `id` = 1 from `cg_resp` with the new email address and the rest of them (`equip_info.cg_resp_id` and `cg_resp.id`) to remain the same.

I would like to maintain the original reference of `cg_resp_id` from table `equip_info` if the name of responsible is the same, so it's necessary to avoid situation like delete and insert a new one.

How can be done this in one [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) sql sequence?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to do this in one sql statement? You could try to `select` the name from your database. If the resulting set is empty you use an `insert` statement, if the set contains the name you call the `update` statement.

Comment: It's not absolutely necessary... if possible, otherwise I will do it classical.

Comment: Update cg_resp WHERE id=1

Comment: u can use `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite UPSERT / UPDATE OR INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277373/sqlite-upsert-update-or-insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INSERT OR REPLACE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) which does exactly what you want : insert a new row when the name does not exists or update otherwise.

Comment: REPLACE deletes the old row if it exists.

Comment: Be careful, INSERT OR REPLACE deletes the row and inserts a new one with a new key, so if you have autogenerated keys and leverage them, you will be out of luck. I haven't found an elegant way to do what you're asking yet but will keep looking.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite has no built-in mechanism that would not delete the existing row.

The easiest way to do this is to put the logic into your application:

```py
cursor = db.execute("SELECT ...")
if cursor.empty:
    db.execute("INSERT ...")
else:
    db.execute("UPDATE ...")
```

If your language allows to read the number of affected rows, it is possible to do this with two SQL commands:

```py
db.execute("UPDATE ...")
if db.rowcount == 0:
    db.execute("INSERT ...")
```