# sqlite3 in python 2.7: Comparing DB values with CSV values

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, sqlite

I have this code, it reads a csv file for the 2 first columns and appends a list from each row.

```
            with open(self.selected_file[0], 'rb') as csv_file:
                itemids = []
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar="\"")
                for row in csv_reader:
                    itemids.append([row[0], row[1]])
```

I have a database that already contains 2 tables, each for every item respectively. I wish to check every row of the csv file (which are pairs of strings). If both strings are unique to their respective table (meaning row[0] is unique to the first item table in my db, and row[1] unique to my second item table), then add those values to their respective tables. I tried the following:

```
        for item in itemids:
            first_itemids = db_cursor.execute('''SELECT itemid FROM items_one''').fetchall()
            second_itemds = db_cursor.execute('''SELECT itemid from items_two''').fetchall()
            try:
                if not item[0] in first_itemids and not item[1] in second_itemids:
                    db_cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO items_one(itemid) VALUES (?)''', (item[0], ))
                    db_cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO items_two(itemid) VALUES (?)''', (item[1], ))
                    db_conn.commit()
```

However this check `if not item[0] in first_itemids and not item[1] in second_itemids` always evaluates to true, so duplicate non unique items are being added. I also tried the other way around 
    
    `if item[0] in first_itemids or item[1] in second_itemids:
        pass`

but that also failed

Note: These aren't my actual variable names, I don't know if same column names in different tables under the same DB can cause problems, but mines don't anyway - I just changed it for the sake of readability.

Edit:

I also tried checking each csv row before appending it to my item list like so:

```
            with open(self.selected_file[0], 'rb') as csv_file:
                itemids = []
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar="\"")
                first_itemids = db_cursor.execute('''SELECT itemid FROM items_one''').fetchall()
                second_itemids = db_cursor.execute('''SELECT itemid from items_two''').fetchall()
                for row in csv_reader:
                    if row[0] not in first_itemds and row[1] not in second_itemids:
                        itemids.append([row[0], row[1]])
```

And then just insert the lists' value to the DB. No good as well

Comment: Seems that you call the same SELECT queries for each item in the csv file. I would suggest doing the selects before the for loop.

Comment: Is it possible that you have the item in one table but not the other? This could possibly cause duplicate entries. I would also make sure that the values are really exact. A blank space can make the values different.

Comment: You're correct - I do call the same SELECT query for each item. This way you can check if there was a duplicate item in the csv file.
As for your other question, I check using DB browser - I have both items when trying to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an "upsert" to put unique items in each table:

```
for item in itemids:
    db_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO items_one(itemid) VALUES (?) WHERE (SELECT changes()=0) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT itemid FROM items_two WHERE itemid = ?)', (item[0], item[1]))
    db_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO items_two(itemid) VALUES (?) WHERE (SELECT changes()=0)', (item[1],))
    db_conn.commit()
```

But this will not fail if the other item is in the other table.

This is taken from another question on [upsert in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277373/sqlite-upsert-update-or-insert).

You should also be able to extend each query to check if the item is unique in the other table:

```
db_cursor.execute('''
    INSERT INTO items_one(itemid)
    VALUES (?)
    WHERE (SELECT changes()=0)
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT itemid FROM items_two
            WHERE itemid = ?
        )
''', (item[0], item[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out... I was comparing item[0] and item[1] which were strings to tuples of unicode, even though I thought python was capable of performing this check.

I changed my if clause to

`if not (item[0],) in first_itemids and not (item[1],) in second_itemids:`