# SQLite: get updated field after upsert

Tags: sqlite

SQLite (and other RDBMS, like PostgreSQL) allow you to perform an insert, and if there's a conflict, execute an update instead. However, getting the final value that was updated seems tricky.

Take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50718957/341772) as an example:

```sql
INSERT INTO players (user_name, age)
  VALUES('steven', 32) 
  ON CONFLICT(user_name) 
  DO UPDATE SET age=excluded.age;
```

Suppose I actually needed to know what `age` was ultimately set to. With PostgreSQL, you can say `RETURNING age`, while trying the same thing with SQLite (3.34.0[1], at least), this seems to be a syntax error. If I simply perform a read operation right after, it's possible that another operation will have swooped in and updated the row after my write completed and before my read started, thus returning a misleading result to the original caller.

1. Is there any equivalent syntax to `RETURNING` that SQLite supports to atomically write and read as described?
2. If not, is there some other pattern I should follow, perhaps `begin transaction-write-read-commit`?

Thanks!

---

[1] xerial/sqlite-jdbc 3.34.0 specifically.

Comment: In https://sqlite.org/draft/matrix/lang_returning.html there's this mention _The RETURNING syntax has been supported by SQLite since version 3.35.0 (pending)._

Comment: Wrap both operations in a transaction, yes.